# Como acceder a un Agente desde otro servidor diferente al TFS

Tags: azure, build, tfs

Tengo un servidor corriendo Team Foundation Server 2018, el cual tiene tiene unos agentes configurados dentro de otro servidor A de la red, entonces quiero cambiar los agentes a un servidor B
¿Como hago para que el TFS apunte al servidor B por los agentes?

Comment: Tengo entendido que son los Agentes los que se suscriben a TFS. Es decir, cuando descargas el agente, ya debería venir configurado para que se Auto-Registre en el servidor TFS.

Answer (score 1):

Para configurar los agentes que apunte a otro servidor, deberías "configurarlos  nuevamente"

Es decir, si ya tienes el agente instalado y configurado, deberias:

1. Remover el agente de la maquina
2. [Configurarlo nuevamente](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops), apuntando al nuevo servidor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Enlaces que te puede ayudar

- [Self-hosted Windows agents](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops)